# JS array find value's index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of integers. How can a determine a value's index depending on array, if I was to insert it into the array, so that no value before it is bigger.

Example:

```
let value = 3941;

calcOrder(value);

calcOrder(value) {
    let array = [3002,2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342, etc..]
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Result: 
According to this example, my function should return 5 ( cause 3941 < 9342 but more than other values in array ).

Comment: That's a simple `for` loop with some basic math operations...

Comment: This question is underspecified because it doesn't say whether the desired index should be the index of a sorted array or based on the current order. It's convenient that the answer should be 5 in the example, but what if the array is: `[10000, 3002,2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342, 1]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` method of arrays:

```js
let value = 3941,
    array = [3002,2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342];
    
let result = array.filter(v => v < value).length;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a loop to check the logic and count the numbers using length

**DEMO**

```js
function countOthers(value) {
  return function(element, index, array) {
    return (element < value);
  }
}
var filtered = [3002,2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342].filter(countOthers(3941)).length;
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

For an `O(n)` solution that doesn't require creating an intermediate array, use `reduce`: start at 0, add one to the accumulator when the item you're iterating over is smaller than the value whose position you're looking for:

```js
const array = [3002,2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342];

const calcOrder = value => array.reduce((a, num) => num < value ? a + 1 : a, 0);
console.log(calcOrder(3941));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.forEach()` to loop over the array and increase the `count` value if the number is less than the `value`:

```js
let value = 3941;
function calcOrder(value) {
  let array = [3002, 2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342]
  let count = 0;
  array.forEach((item) => {
    if (item < value) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(calcOrder(value));
```

You can use old way to get that result without using array functions to make it work in IE browsers and older versions of web browsers:

```js
let value = 3941;
function calcOrder(value) {
  let array = [3002, 2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342]
  let count = 0;
  array.forEach(function(item){
    if (item < value) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(calcOrder(value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` to get the array of all the elements which are less than the value. Finally take the length of the array:

```js
let value = 3941;

console.log(calcOrder(value));

function calcOrder(value) {
    let array = [3002,2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342]
    return array.filter(i => i<value).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a "sort" and "findIndex" logic.

```
var array = [3002,2934, 1044, 2848, 1293, 9342]


var calOrder = (num) => ((index = array.sort().findIndex(val => val > num)), index == -1 ? array.length : index)

calOrder(3941) // 5
```